# How to save ID passed by activity (android)

Tags: java, android, json

Hello how can I save an ID, because in my app every time I minimize and then return the data coming NULL.

This ID comes outa activity and server for call data via json.

Comment: Use sharedPrefrences or SQLlite

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for persisting the data. The simplest way to achieve this would be saving it in Shared Preferences.

Developer link has good information on how to implement this - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

You can save the value  Key, Value pair and then retrieve it when the app is up again.

Answer (score 0):

Handle onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(ID, mId);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Restore state members from saved instance
    mId= savedInstanceState.getInt(ID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i can use the Shared Preferences to save the temporary data.

See the following code.

add this fields in your string.xml file with key.

```
<string name="prefs_user_login">prefs123</string>
<string name="prefs_user_id">userid</string>
<string name="prefs_uname">username</string>
<string name="prefs_pass">password</string>
```

and then then put the following code into your Activity for saving the data

```
 Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.prefs_user_login), 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(getString(R.string.prefs_user_id), UserId);
            editor.putString(getString(R.string.prefs_uname), edtUserName.getText().toString());
            editor.putString(getString(R.string.prefs_pass), edtPassword.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
```

and then put the following code for retrieve the data from shared preferences.

```
 Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.prefs_user_login), 0);
    String UserId = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.prefs_user_id), "");
    String UserName = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.prefs_uname), "");
    String Password = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.prefs_pass), "");
```

use the following code for remove the shared Preferences.

```
 Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.prefs_user_login), 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit().clear();
    editor.remove(getString(R.string.prefs_user_login));
    editor.commit();
```

I hope it will work for you.